# How to pass both the model value and javascript value to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am submitting the form which has the css dropdownlist for gender how to submit the gender selected value to controller i am getting tht value null

```
<div class="regi-field-set">

            <div id="ddlgender" class='selectBox' tabindex="7">

                      <span class='selected' id="gender">gender</span> 
        <span class='selectArrow'>&#9660</span>
                     <div id="disableasterisk5" style="padding-bottom:8px"><span class="required">*</span></div>
                  <div class="selectOptions" id="genderSelectOptions">

                <span class="selectOption" id="ddlgen">male</span>
                      <span class="selectOption" id="ddlgen1">female</span>


        </div>
                 </div>

<div class="regi-field-set">
                   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB, new { @class = "jq_watermark", placeholder = "date of birth", tabindex = "8",id = "DOB",title = "please enter date of birth" })
                   <div id="disableasterisk7"><span class="required">*</span></div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
              </div>
```

how to pass both value to controller all other fields in the form are using html.helper fields only gender field is css implemented

Is there any way to pass the entire model and the gender selected value to controller

please help

Comment: What's your controller code look like?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, the answer of passing to the View both the "model" and a list of something else to use in a dropdown list can be done by the following code:

Controller

```
         ....
         var model = service.GetMyThing(id);
         var genderList= service.GetGenders().Select(p => 
                   new SelectListItem { Value = p.Id.ToString(), Text = p.Name }).ToList();
         ViewBag.GenderList = genderList; 
         return View(model);
```

View

```
         ....
         @Html.DropDownList("GenderId",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.GenderList)
         ....
          <div class="regi-field-set">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB, new { @class = "jq_watermark", placeholder = "date of birth", tabindex = "8",id = "DOB",title = "please enter date of birth" })
               <div id="disableasterisk7"><span class="required">*</span></div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
          </div>
```

**Note**: this is NOT the only solution, custom HTMLHelpers can be used to draw the combo.

Answer (score 0):

using ajax you can achieve this : don't use form & declare your attributes like this in tags:

```
<a href="someLink">@Model.idText</a>
<input type="text" id="textValue"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
```

jquery:

```
 $(function (e) {
        //    Insert
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "some url path",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { textField: $('#textValue').val(), idField: '@Model.idText' },
                success: function (result) {
                    //some code if success
                },
                error: function () {
                    //some code if failed
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
      });
```

Hopefully it will help you